# Software to compress, and browse, a website with 1000s of pages

Tags: offline, web-browser, archiving, file-compression

I have a local copy of a website with 98,000 pages (I just checked). The uncompressed size is somewhere around 8gb. I'd like to put it all in one file maybe, and compress it, then just use a standard browser to view it. Is there software with which I can do this?

I don't even know what keywords to Google for. (I later searched for 'web archive'.)

- I use Firefox 43.0 on Windows 8 64-bit.
- I already downloaded the site, I don't want to download it again via Scrapbook or similar Firefox plugins because it took me about 60 hours (because I used low bandwidth to be nice). The links in the website have already been "localized" to work on my external USB drive.
- I found [Mozilla Archive Format](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/) plugin but I'd still have to download the site again it seems, and my OS may not handle a single 4GB file.

EDIT:

**File composition:** It's mainly html (text) and text can be compressed  [65% or more](http://compression.ca/act/act-text.html) via zip. 2) Format is 98,000 html files, unknown number of images, no movies or audio (I disallowed those) using up 8GB of space. [Compression.ca](http://compression.ca) is a really cool website that compares compression rates on different types of files with different compressors even if it hasn't been updated in a while.

**Goal:** Goal is for the web site to take up less space and be easier to copy to a flash drive.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that not every file (uncompressed) takes up the whole disk cluster so with 98,000 files there is a LOT of wasted disk space in the unused parts of 98,000 disk clusters. So putting this in a single ZIP file saves space by eliminating wasted space in each disk cluster.

Comment: For Windows? And free I guess? Please [edit] into your question.

Comment: Do you know what comprises the bulk of the data? If it is images, compression probably won't buy you much.

Comment: What format is your local downloaded copy of the site? Also, what is your main goal in doing this? To shrink the size?

Comment: 1) It's mainly html (text) and text can be compressed an average of 50% via zip. 2) Format is 98,000 html files, unknown number of images, no movies or audio (I disallowed those) using up 8GB of space. Goal is for the web site to take up less space and be easier to copy to a flash drive. NOTE: Keep in mind that not every file (uncompressed) takes up the whole disk cluster so with 98,000 files there is a LOT of wasted disk space in the unused parts of 98,000 disk clusters. So putting this in a single ZIP file saves space by eliminating wasted space in each disk cluster.

Comment: When I looked yesterday, logical disk space taken up is 8.19gb, physical disk space taken up is 9.1gb. So I'm wasting 1GB, or 11%, of space right there.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility, which I have to admit I haven't tried, is to use just about any compression software that can create a ISO or ZIP file, *some of the mount tools can do this for you and some support other formats as well*, to compress/save the directory tree to a single file and then use a tool that will allow you to "mount" that file as if it were a separate drive.

- Work from existing download - Yes
- Use standard browser - Providing your existing download works Yes.
- Single file saving space - Yes *note that if the web site contains a lot of images you will still save space due to the lack of "wasted" space after each file*
- Windows - Yes

### Possible Mount Tools

- [Pismo File Mount](http://pismotec.com/pfm/) - Free
- [Magic ISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) - Free
- [WinArchiver](http://www.winarchiver.com/virtual-drive.htm) - US$29.95
- [WinMount](http://www.winmount.com/) - US$49

Comment: you can create a compressed iso image (http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-compressiso.htm) and then you can mount a compressed disk and view all your precious pages with a low space footprint. aka without decompressing the whole thing.

Comment: A compressed ISO file, of course! And windows 8 supports/mounts ISO files natively. Good idea. It took me 90 minutes to copy the files to a flash drive via USB 2.0. I think that particular flash drive (Sandisk 32gb) is only USB 2.0. I got it like 2 years ago.

Comment: Just want to make sure: Can Windows 8 mount a compressed ISO file directly? Or does it have to be uncompressed first before I mount it? Because the ISO file will likely reside on a flash drive. Also, how crippled is the free MagicISO?

Comment: @Bulrush I haven't tried mounting compressed ISO on Windows 8. Not very crippled.